# Not able to get rid of a warning and solve that error too

Tags: software-installation, kubernetes

Ignoring file 'kubernetes.list.d' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

I got this error while installing kubernetes. It's not installed yet. I am trying to remove the file that's making error and I can't. I need some assistance , please

Also, what is kubernetes.list.d ? Under etc, I could find sources.list and it has some configuration lines but list.d ..I couldn't find it.

Comment: You've not provided your release details (*variations exist between releases thus we can only be generic that may or may not fit your unstated release*) but the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty on most releases; so the file mentioned in your error message (`kubernetes.list.d`) was added by someone with `sudo` rights on your system but was added incorrectly. That is the file you need to correct.